# Remove attributes in Mongoid before_save loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I figured that instead of leaving certain attributes in parent and embedded documents nil/null (e.g. total of an order if no price exists), I better not save them at all. How can I remove attributes that are nil before saving?

```
# embedded order position for each order
class Orderitem
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :quantity, :type => Integer
  field :unit_price, :type => Integer
  field :total, :type => Integer
  field :economical_potential, :type => Integer

  embedded_in :order
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :item

  before_save :remove_empty_fields

  private

  def remove_empty_fields
    attributes.each do |attr_name, value|
      if value.nil?
        # don't save attribute
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove attributes from your model? In that case, I would add another model called  `unit` and add `:price` as an attribute. Then add a function to `Orderitem` called `def total_of_unit` which will return the total based on the number of units and their price.

In code it would look like this:

```
class Orderitem
  ...
  field :quantity, :type => Integer
  # drop :unit_price
  # drop :total
  field :economical_potential, :type => Integer
  ...
  has_many :units
  ...
  def total
    @total = 0
    self.units.each do |unit|
      @total = @total + unit.price
    end
    return @total
  end
end
```

Unit would look like this:

```
class Unit
  field :unit_price, :type => Integer
  belongs_to :Orderitem
end
```

Comment: That's a great way to calculate the total. I wanted to not save attributes that are nil. For instance, someone orders an item with no price, than the total will be nil/null. Instead of saving a total of nil/null, I thought I would just not save the attribute. For the parent document it seems I actually can't save nil/null values (attributes with nil don't get saved) but for embedded docs Mongoid does save them with "null". I figured best would be to have consistent data.

Answer (score -1):

Mongoid supports #unset, so you can use something like this:

```
order_item.unset(:total)
```